# AngularJS - show/hide elements from rootscope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, show, show-hide

I am listening for an application losing network connectivity by adding an event listener.

When the app goes offline i need to show a message.

The following code does not seem to work for me.

I add the event listener in the application run method so that it is globally available:

```
document.addEventListener("offline", function() {
    $rootScope.offline = true;
}, false);
```

Then in my index.html I show hide a message based on that $rootScope variable:

```
<div id="network-msg" ng-show="$root.offline">
    <div class="full-overlay" ng-show="$root.offline">
        <p class="txt-center">No internet connection</p>
        <p class="txt-center">Trying to re-connect</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i go offline i can see that the varibale is being updated but the message does not show.  So if i output:

```
{{$root.offline}}
```

on page i can see it switch from false to true correctly but still message is not shown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the value is updated in a dom event handler, the changes have to be done within a [$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply) callback

```
document.addEventListener("offline", function() {
    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
        $rootScope.offline = true;
    })
}, false);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difference between the `ng-model` directive that identifies the changes and the need for `$apply` here? It worked for me too. I setup a `$rootScope.$on` in the `run` handler and the only way I could get the view to respond to the change was to use this. I raised that by calling the `$scope.$emit` FYI.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud [see this](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/) and [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) to get a basic idea about why [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) is required

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud not sure about your problem with problem with `$on()` and `$emit()` can you explain the problem... also if possible try to recreate the issue in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CNNRp/)

Comment: I had a [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499153/ngshow-on-parent-variable) that kind of spells out how I was using it. I added an answer because you actually answered my question! I +1'd this answer BTW.