# ngShow on $parent variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got something running in the `$rootScope` to set an application-wide value for `userLoggedIn`:

```
mod.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.userLoggedIn = false;

    $rootScope.$on('loggedIn', function(event, args) {
        $rootScope.userLoggedIn = true;
    });
});
```

and when the user is logged in I leverage `$emit` to raise that event:

```
mod.controller('FacebookController', function($scope) {
    $scope.loggedIn = function() {
        $scope.$emit('loggedIn');
    };
});
```

and this is working.

Next I've configured an attribute directive to bring the `$rootScope` into view:

```
mod.directive('rootScope', function() {
    return {
        scope: { userLoggedIn: '@' },
        restrict: 'A'
    };
})
```

However, when I use it on the elements to show/hide based off its value it doesn't work:

```
<div class="row" root-scope>
    <div class="panel callout radius" ng-show="!userLoggedIn">
```

and:

```
<form name="listForm" root-scope
    novalidate ng-submit="listForm.$valid && model.save()"
    ng-show="userLoggedIn">
```

Why doesn't that value come into scope? When I look at the angular scope in Chrome the variable isn't in scope. It is on the `$parent` though as expected.

**UPDATE**

So, if I use `$root.userLoggedIn` it does reference the property as expected, however, the view still doesn't respond when the value is changed. For example, if I reload the page it's `false` initially, but after Facebook is done logging in it's set to `true`; the view doesn't respond.

Comment: Inject `$rootScope` in contoller then in view use `ng-show="!$root.userLoggedIn"`

Comment: but why you need the rootScope directive its not needed I think, if you dont have userLoggedIn in your scopes , binding its in view angular will lookup into scopes and will achive the rootScope where you already have this property and will use that value, its making sense ?

Comment: @Satpal while `$root.userLoggedIn` does in fact reference that property, the view still doesn't respond when the value is changed. For example, if I reload the page it's `false` initially, but after Facebook is done logging in it's set to true; the view doesn't respond.

Comment: @Satpal, the problem was I also needed to use the `$apply` on the `$rootScope` to get the view to respond to the change. I then could in fact use `$root.userLoggedIn`; please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was unbelievably simple, and leveraged a comment too. I did in fact just need the view to use `$root.userLoggedIn`, but I also needed to leverage the `$apply`:

```
mod.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.userLoggedIn = false;

    $rootScope.$on('loggedIn', function(event, args) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            $rootScope.userLoggedIn = true;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Its great that you found the solution and shared with us.

Answer (score 0):

```
scope: { userLoggedIn: '@' }
```

Your directive expects the HTML attribute `userLoggedIn`, but there is none in your HTML. Also keep in mind that `@` always resolves to a `String`.

The second and more important point is that only your `root-scope` directive operates in the isolate scope, but not `ng-show`. In other words: Using `root-scope` has no effect whatsoever. Based only on the code you presented, your example works as expected.